# Node.js: Making Hello World page public

Tags: node.js

I copied the Hello World example from

```
https://nodejs.org/en/about/
```

and it works fine on my Ubuntu cloud instance. Now I'd like to make the Hello World page visible to the entire Internet. What changes are required to the code to accomplish this?

Update: When port is set to 80 and hostname is set to the instance IP address, the following errors are generated when attempting to initiate a node.js session:

```
ubuntu@instance04:~/NodeJS/NodeHW$ node index01
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES <my_ip_address>:80
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1334:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1501:7)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:686:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Comment: you need to open ports

Comment: Where did you get your instance from? AWS? DigitalOcean? Azure? You will need to allow traffic through the port that you're listening to. Some cloud service providers require you to explicitly allow that port through the network settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to view the page on your server using its IP. But you may need to take a couple of steps first:

1. Take note of which port your Node app is listening on. 3000? 80? In production (i.e. on your cloud server instance), it would be customary to run your application on the default HTTP port, which is 80. But other ports are fine to use too.
2. Depending on your cloud provider, you may have to adjust its **Network Settings** before it allows any inbound traffic from the internet through to your server. On AWS, for example, each instance is bound to a **Security Group**. Think of this as a cloud-level firewall that controls internet access to and from your server. On AWS, again as an example, you'd have to adjust your **Security Group Inbound Rules** to allow TCP connections to be established to port **80** (or whichever port your Node app is listening on). Here's a sample picture of what it looks like. In this example, I've opened port 80 of my server for TCP traffic. Open whichever port that your Node app is listening on. The protocol for HTTP is TCP.

[image: AWS Security Group Inbound Rules allowing HTTP traffic through port 80]

3. Furthermore, you may have to also adjust your server's internal firewall settings. On Ubuntu, in order to check the status of the firewall, issue this command:

> `$ sudo ufw status`

If the status is `inactive`, then it means Ubuntu is not enforcing any firewall rules. If it's `active`, however, you need to make sure that it is allowing incoming traffic to your Node app's port. I'll let you research how to adjust [`ufw`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) settings.

4. Finally, obtain the **Public** facing IP address or assigned domain name of your server. On AWS, this information is available on your instance details view:

[image: Instance public DNS and IP]

So, now you should be able to browse, from anywhere on the internet to your server's public IP and your Node app's port and view the page.

`http://ip:port`

If your server's IP is 123.123.123.123 and your Node app is listening on port 3000, then the address would be `http://123.123.123.123:3000`. If your Node app is listening on port 80, then there's no need to specify the port when you browse. So you can simply go to: `http://123.123.123.123`

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I have 'ingress' set on port 80, but not 'egress'. When I try to run the code with the hostname set to my server's IP address, and the port set to 80, running the code with node.js generates an error.

Comment: I'm not sure I can show the error in a comment without the line breaks being lost, so I will edit my original question.

Comment: Incidentally, I checked sudo ufw status and it is inactive.

Comment: Thanks for the `ufw` info. Can you please edit your code and change these lines: `server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/);
});` to simply `server.listen(80);` and let me know what happens when you try to run that?

Comment: For your info, that error is complaining that the server is unable to bind to (start listening on) that IP/hostname/port combination. By removing the `hostname` parameter from `server.listen()` your app will listen on any IP/hostname on the port you specify. If the error persists, it could be that another application (e.g. nginx, etc.) has occupied port 80. So you can either stop any other application that's currently bound to port 80, or you can change your Node app to listen on a different port (in which case you'd have to add a new ingress rule to your server settings.)

Comment: Made the change per your suggestion. What looks like the same error is generated. I frankly have no idea how to check which other processes might be bound to port 80 (although I can and will research that question). Will also look into trying another port.

Comment: Yes, please try another port (e.g. 3000) to see if the app can successfully bind and start listening. And also try port 80 with sudo: `sudo node index01`

Comment: @Argent Curious if any of these tips helped and you managed to publish your page?

Comment: I did finally publish my Hello World page. I see that you suggested using a higher port, and using sudo. I think I failed to pick up on these suggestions as you did not specify that when a port below 1024 is used, sudo *must* precede the node command.

Answer (score 0):

I received the answer from tech support at DreamHost.com. I quote: "The problem is that in order to bind to any port lower than 1000, you need to use sudo."

I am using port 80, so the following works:

```
sudo node index01
```

Update: The exact limit is 1024, i.e., when a port lower than 1024 is used sudo must precede the node command.